# Function continuous substitution

Tags: functions

Let $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}.$$

Evaluate $f(f(f(f(f(f(1))))))$. 
Shortcut or easy way for this. Really need to know that concept. Or do we have to do it with brute force?

Comment: Do a couple, and look for a pattern.

Comment: You might want to use $f(a/b) = b/(a + b)$. This shows that if you write $1$, $f(1)$, $f(f(1))$, etc., as a sequence of fractions, then the numerator of any term in the sequence will be the denominator of the previous one, and its denominator will be the sum of the numerator and denominator of the previous one.

Comment: ... so the problem boils down to studying the convergents of the continued fraction of $\varphi=[1;1,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots]$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = 1/(1+x), \\ f(f(x)) = 1/(1 + (1/(1+x)), \\ f(f(f(x))) = 1/(1+1/(1 + (1/(1+x)))  , ...$

$f(1) = 1/2, \\ f(f(1)) = 2/3, \\f(f(f(1))) = 3/5, ...  $

Do you see a pattern forming?

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
f(a/b) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac ab} = \frac{1}{(a + b)/b} = \frac{b}{a + b}
$$

Comment: This seems more of a (very useful) comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Using the [Fibonacci Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number):
$$
\frac1{1+\frac{F_n+xF_{n-1}}{F_{n+1}+xF_n}}=\frac1{\frac{F_{n+2}+xF_{n+1}}{F_{n+1}+xF_n}}=\frac{F_{n+1}+xF_n}{F_{n+2}+xF_{n+1}}
$$
Note that with $n=0$, $\frac{F_n+xF_{n-1}}{F_{n+1}+xF_n}=x$.

Thus, the composition of $n$ copies of $f$ would be
$$
\frac{F_n+xF_{n-1}}{F_{n+1}+xF_n}
$$